# Raising Alternator Voltage

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, dc, generator

Does anyone have a good idea on how I could raise the voltage from a 12v car alternator to 48v dc for use in a 48v wind system? Could I put a dc negative voltage of 36v into the regulator field sensing pin to trick the regulator? Can I somehow switch out the voltage regulator for another one or change how much it regulates it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to make the car alternator to produce 48V instead of 12V provided enough RPM. It's not a very good idea to trick the regulator the way you described. A better solution could be to tune a ready-made 42- or 48-volt regulator to get the voltage you need. You could also use a high-power zener together with a completely mechanical regulator.

Comment: According to the below article in **Mother Earth News**, you should be able to get 48V out of an alternator with about 1500 RPM, given 12V on the field windings. Modern alternators, unfortunately, usually have the regulator built-in so some surgery would be required. http://www.motherearthnews.com/diy/make-your-own-emergency-power-plant.aspx?PageId=2#ArticleContent

Answer (score 1):

The output voltage of a common vehicle alternator is controlled by its internal rectifier/regulator module (although external regulation was once common, it's not now). Opening the casing on many modern alternators to replace its regulator with one of the target voltage is not an easy task; putting it back together can be even harder; when the alternator's rectifier circuit failed in my 1973 car, however, I managed to open the casing and replace it.
The added problem is fitting your replacement regulator inside. After disconnecting/removing the original module, you may have to hardwire from the alternator to your externally mounted replacement regulator.

Answer (score -2):

Use a dc dc converter to boost the voltage, example: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B00DR4TV2O?pc_redir=1400891952&robot_redir=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DR4TV2O)

Comment: An alternator has rectification inside, you can't put an transformer inside so you'll have to explain exactly how you propose this would work.

Comment: @placeholder: It isn't difficult to remove the diodes and get direct access to the AC output of the alternator. It is 3-phase, however, so that would complicate things a bit.

Comment: @placeholder you're right, you'd have to bypass the built-in rectifier. The better option is probably to use a dc dc converter, which is probably more practical, not that this is even a practical thing to do in the first place.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @daniel grillo Ok I changed it